# REGEX : Parsing a Large string

Tags: java, android, regex, linux, unix

I'm reading an `InputStream` to a `String` using the following code.

```
public String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    try {
        return new Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

However I'm getting a very large `String` as output. How can I parse it to just get values for`Free blocks` and `Block count` as two seperate strings?

```
03-01 09:28:25.772: I/System.out(8849): tune2fs 1.41.10 (10-Feb-2009)
03-01 09:28:25.772: I/System.out(8849): Filesystem volume name:   <none>
03-01 09:28:25.772: I/System.out(8849): Last mounted on:          <not available>
03-01 09:28:25.772: I/System.out(8849): Filesystem UUID:          c6a5907b-71b3-4686-9ed1-8dd932c6359b
03-01 09:28:25.772: I/System.out(8849): Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
03-01 09:28:25.772: I/System.out(8849): Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
03-01 09:28:25.772: I/System.out(8849): Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr dir_index filetype sparse_super
03-01 09:28:25.772: I/System.out(8849): Filesystem flags:         unsigned_directory_hash 
03-01 09:28:25.772: I/System.out(8849): Default mount options:    (none)
03-01 09:28:25.772: I/System.out(8849): Filesystem state:         clean
03-01 09:28:25.772: I/System.out(8849): Errors behavior:          Continue
03-01 09:28:25.772: I/System.out(8849): Filesystem OS type:       Linux
03-01 09:28:25.772: I/System.out(8849): Inode count:              24480
03-01 09:28:25.772: I/System.out(8849): Block count:              97656
03-01 09:28:25.772: I/System.out(8849): Reserved block count:     4882
03-01 09:28:25.772: I/System.out(8849): Free blocks:              90433
03-01 09:28:25.772: I/System.out(8849): Free inodes:              24469
03-01 09:28:25.772: I/System.out(8849): First block:              1
03-01 09:28:25.772: I/System.out(8849): Block size:               1024
03-01 09:28:25.772: I/System.out(8849): Fragment size:            1024
03-01 09:28:25.772: I/System.out(8849): Blocks per group:         8192
03-01 09:28:25.772: I/System.out(8849): Fragments per group:      8192
03-01 09:28:25.772: I/System.out(8849): Inodes per group:         2040
03-01 09:28:25.772: I/System.out(8849): Inode blocks per group:   255
03-01 09:28:25.772: I/System.out(8849): Filesystem created:       Thu Mar  1 04:01:37 2012
03-01 09:28:25.772: I/System.out(8849): Last mount time:          n/a
03-01 09:28:25.772: I/System.out(8849): Last write time:          Thu Mar  1 04:01:37 2012
03-01 09:28:25.772: I/System.out(8849): Mount count:              0
03-01 09:28:25.772: I/System.out(8849): Maximum mount count:      35
03-01 09:28:25.772: I/System.out(8849): Last checked:             Thu Mar  1 04:01:37 2012
03-01 09:28:25.772: I/System.out(8849): Check interval:           15552000 (6 months)
03-01 09:28:25.772: I/System.out(8849): Next check after:         Tue Aug 28 04:01:37 2012
03-01 09:28:25.772: I/System.out(8849): Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
03-01 09:28:25.772: I/System.out(8849): Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
03-01 09:28:25.772: I/System.out(8849): First inode:              11
03-01 09:28:25.772: I/System.out(8849): Inode size:           128
03-01 09:28:25.772: I/System.out(8849): Journal inode:            8
03-01 09:28:25.772: I/System.out(8849): Default directory hash:   half_md4
03-01 09:28:25.772: I/System.out(8849): Directory Hash Seed:      fb1c85fc-7de0-431e-be07-aa42bee66e7d
03-01 09:28:25.772: I/System.out(8849): Journal backup:           inode blocks
03-01 09:28:25.819: I/System.out(8849): length = 1512
03-01 09:28:25.819: I/System.out(8849): 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Edited] Sorry didn't realize what you were doing with your scanner:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\n");
    scanner.findWithinHorizon(Pattern.compile("Block\\scount:\\s*(\\d+)"), 0);
    String blockCount = scanner.match().group(1);
    scanner.findWithinHorizon(Pattern.compile("Free\\sblocks:\\s*(\\d+)"), 0);
    String freeBlocks = scanner.match().group(1);
```

That will give you just the values of free blocks and block count.  For example, *freeBlocks* would equal "90433", and *blockCount* would equal "97656".

Comment: I get `03-01 10:07:49.436: W/System.err(9432): java.lang.IllegalStateException: No successful match so far
`. :(

Comment: It matches now but returns the whole line, the problem was with order. BlockCount should be placed first.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(is);
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    // If line contains information
        // Parse Line
    // Else
        // continue
}
```

I'll leave the logic of trying to determine if the line contains the information you're looking for up to you.